# How do I pull text from SQL (MySQL for example) to fill out a text template? General advice appreciated

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this question is too general for specifics but general advice is appreciated.

I want to use MySQL data to fill out text templates. I have thousands of records, and want each records information inserted in specific locations on a template.

I want to "generate" the thousands of articles instead of inserting them manually.

This IS NOT for spam content, I own a literary agency and want a publisher profile for all publishers that accept unsolicited manuscripts. I just want to put their publisher description, submission link, etc into the template.

Basically like this:

```
Article text Article text Article text Article text 
(text pulled from MySQL)
Article text Article text Article text Article text 
(link pulled from MySQL)
```

Any advice is appreciated. I am very computer savvy but not a programmer. I will take all good advice & do my own research, I just need to be pointed into the right direction.

Comment: If you are interested only in `MySQL` do not tag other databases. I went ahead removed the other tags. In any case this too broad a question to be appropriate for StackOverflow. I would suggest searching on 'filling text template from database data' or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional approach to solving a problem like this is to write an application in a general purpose programming language (such as go, python, etc) that calls MySQL for the parts fetched from the database and uses its own code for the rest of the functionality (authentication, user experience, etc).

However, if you want an all MySQL solution, I would do something like this:

```
select concat('article text article text', column_name_1
  , 'more article text', column_name_2) as text
from table_name
where whatever = something;
```

This will concatenate the fixed text (eg, 'article text article text') with the variable text fetched from the database (eg, content of column_name_1).

I've used this technique to interleave markup instructions (eg, HTML) with data fetched from a database.